# Jenkins SCM polling is not working when hosted on AWS Linux 18.04.1

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, polling

> **EDIT:**
>
> I found out that, on UBUNTU 16.0.4 the SCM Service is working fine and I do not face the problem. However, I'm having this problem on
>   Ubuntu 18.0.4.
>
> Any idea how can I check the SCM service logs?

---

**Problem:**

- Jenkins is not able to Poll for changes in the git repo. However, if
  manually triggered, the recent changes are fetched and then the job
  is built.

**Jenkins Config:**

- Jenkins master machine is in AWS cloud behind a load balancer.
- All slaves are in my local network which can connect to Jenkins
  Master and execute jobs as per Master's command.

**Solutions tried so far:**

- I suspected some problem with the local firewall and tried connecting the node to a network which did not have any firewall. Still, this did not work.
- I tried deleting the existing nodes and adding them freshly. Still, it did not work.
- I tried with Bitbucket branch source plugin since all our code is on Bitbucket cloud.

**What I'm expecting to solve this:**

- If anyone has faced this issue before, please let me know how to resolve this.
- Else, I want to know is there any way that I can see the polling logs at
  the system level.
- Please note: Not in the Jenkins (which I know). Please note, I do not
  want to see the logs at https://mydomain/jobs/SCMpollLog as they do
  print only after polling is triggered and then polling is a success
  or not. I want to know the reason behind why polling is not
  occurring.

Pleaes let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: What are logs printed on console for polling? Or even they are available? https://mydomain/jobs/jobname//pollLog
Any errors in master's log file?

Comment: Since the polling itself is not working, there are no errors. However, if I manually trigger the polling, then the logs are populated and they are fine.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I would recommend you using the git hook: it will create an event once the repository has been updated and push it to Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-GitHubhooktriggerforGITScmpolling

Comment: I'm not using Github. I'm using bitbucket. As far as I've understood, for bitbucket, we need to use bitbucket branch source plugin. (which again needs to use polling)

Comment: @VighneshPai check out these docs for BitBucket
https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381288449/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Git+Plugin

webhooks don't use poll, they are based on push messages from CVS to the CI server

Comment: The above-mentioned link is for Bitbucket sever. and its bit different than Bitbucket cloud.