# Jenkins doesn't get notified and doesn't buil when user raise pull request from Bitbucket clou

Tags: jenkins

I have created Jenkins server(v 2.138.3) with bitbucket cloud on ubuntu 16. Jenkins couldn't trigger the build when user raise pull request from bitbucket cloud (Not bitbucket server). But in my project it trigger the build when user commit the code by git command. I followed below link for trigger the build on pull request. But they used bitbucket server. Some options are not available in bitbucket cloud. 
https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/209059847/Triggering+Jenkins+on+new+Pull+Requests

Can any one tell me how to do trigger the build when user raise pull request from bitbucket cloud? and I too stuttering to attach the Html documents of report in mail notification. Here I have attached my screen shot of Jenkins and bitbucket cloud webhook. Please help me to find the exact solution.

```
[Image of Bitbucket pull request builder][1]
[Image Of Poll SCM][2]
[bitbucket_Webhook][3]
[SCM][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtx1i.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvRA6.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT3dZ.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEYn7.png
```

Comment: In Bitbucket webhook settings did you select ‘pull request’ checkbox as one of the triggers ?

Comment: Yes ..i selected pull request - created

Comment: Do you see response 200 for the webhook request when user created PR ? You can enable webhook request logging to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Just goto your job details page and tap on Poll now, and see if the latest changes are pulled? I think polling is the problem while building with the pull request. I too have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53718499/1289629

Comment: yes its polling. but doesnt trigger the build.                                                                                       Git Polling Log
Started on Dec 12, 2018 8:06:00 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4f880cffc7aa8f9f308c4c0d0f8dabbd5fd94713 (origin/test_pr)
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials proper bitbucket creds

Comment: Started on Dec 12, 2018 8:06:00 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 4f880cffc7aa8f9f308c4c0d0f8dabbd5fd94713 (origin/test_pr)
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials proper bitbucket creds
 > /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h https://latchu1@bitbucket.org/latchu1/latchu1.git # timeout=10
Found 18 remote heads on https://latchu1@bitbucket.org/latchu1/latchu1.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/test_pr is: 4f880cffc7aa8f9f308c4c0d0f8dabbd5fd94713 - already built by 74
Done. Took 1.9 sec
No changes

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Stash Pull Request Builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Stash+pullrequest+builder+plugin) to perform this. It worked for me.

---

**Dont forgot to add In advance options :-**

Advanced -> Refspec:

```
+refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Branch Specifier:

```
origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from
```

SCM Config will be like below :- 
[image: SCM Config]

Trigger Config:- 
[image: Trigger Config]

Comment: can you tell me the steps to perform?

Comment: Screenshots and steps added

Comment: what is the stash url in source code management? i followed your screenshot..But doesn't trigger the build when raise a pull request from bitbucket cloud.

Comment: In your case that will be bitbucket's base URL

Comment: I would recommend to go through https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Stash+pullrequest+builder+plugin link..